# What is the inverse cdf / ppf of the logit-normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, python

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60669256/how-do-you-create-a-logit-normal-distribution-in-python/60676356?noredirect=1), I am trying to implement the logit-normal distribution in Python. The provided answer works for me, however, the `rvs` method that draws random variates failes for me. According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) of the pdf class that I am using:

> "The default method _rvs relies on the inverse of the cdf, _ppf, applied to a uniform random variate. In order to generate random variates efficiently, either the default _ppf needs to be overwritten (e.g. if the inverse cdf can expressed in an explicit form) or a sampling method needs to be implemented in a custom _rvs method."

This is what I am trying to figure out, but I couldn't find a description of the inverse logit-normal cdf anywhere. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to generate $X$ where $Y=\log_e\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\right)\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

So generate $Y$, either directly from a normal distribution, or from a $U \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ and $Y = \mu +\sigma\Phi^{-1}(U)$, and then let $X=\frac{e^Y}{e^Y+1}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-Y}}$.  Combine these and you could say $$X=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mu -\sigma\Phi^{-1}(U)}}$$ and in a sense this is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of the logit-normal distribution

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse cumulative normal distribution, correct?

Comment: @mapf - yes, for a standard normal $\mathcal N(0,1)$